# why the url of solrnet always ends with ？

Tags: lucene, solr, solrnet

here is the url send by solrnet

http://localhost:8983/m_review/maincore/select?facet.field=p_catalog_id&facet=true&fq=p_B2BShow%3a%5b1+TO+*%5d&fq=p_review_type%3a1&sort=p_review_date+desc&rows=4&q=*%3a*&?

the url always ends with &?

and the costed time during the search is 10 times slower than the normal url

how to solve this problem?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It may be a bug, but I've never seen any perf or behavior difference because of it. Solr just ignores it.

You might want to try compiling the latest source and see if it fixes your issue. But as I said, I really doubt that's the real cause of a 10x slowdown.